# Chromedriver ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium 4.14.0 and Python 3.11.4 to crawl a website with the following settings:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--lang=en')
options.add_argument('--allow-insecure-localhost')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
```

but get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
  (Session info: chrome=119.0.6045.123)
```

Comment: can you add the website URL as well?

Comment: It is a local private website, but it is too old and we don't have access to its db